# groovy missingpropertyexecption

Tags: groovy

I'm new to groovy. I'm trying to figure out the basic syntax. The following code snippet:

```
def CRITICAL = 2;
def MAJOR = 3;
def MINOR = 9;
def GetPriorityFromString(String priorityStr) {
    switch (priorityStr){
        case "Critical" : return CRITICAL;
        case "Major" : return MAJOR;
        case "Minor" : return MINOR;
    }
    return 0;
}
GetPriorityFromString("Minor")
```

causes this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MINOR for class: Script21
```

What'm I doin wrong?

(And since I'm new to this language, feel free to suggest any "groovier" ways to translate a string into an enumerated value.)

Comment: Put it in a real class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a map

```
def mapping =["CRITICAL": 2, "MAJOR" : 3, "MINOR": 9]
println mapping["MINOR"]
```

As for your original code:
You have a problem with the scope of the variables. If you are in a script context you may not use "def" to declare global variables just leave it out and it will work.

```
CRITICAL = 2;
MAJOR = 3;
MINOR = 9;
def GetPriorityFromString(String priorityStr) {
    switch (priorityStr){
        case "Critical" : return CRITICAL;
        case "Major" : return MAJOR;
        case "Minor" : return MINOR;
    }
    return 0;
}
GetPriorityFromString("Minor")
```

If you put it into a normal class then you have to use the defs

```
class Test {
def CRITICAL = 2;
def MAJOR = 3;
def MINOR = 9;
def GetPriorityFromString(String priorityStr) {
    switch (priorityStr){
        case "Critical" : return CRITICAL;
        case "Major" : return MAJOR;
        case "Minor" : return MINOR;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
new Test().GetPriorityFromString("Minor")
```